# unable to access SharePoint 2010 website from local

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have installed SharePoint foundation 2010 in the MS server 2008 operating system and able to  access Central Administration website from Local system. But I'm when I'm trying to access one of the website which created on Central Administration is not working from local system, but the website is accessible from the server.

It seems nothing happening from local or seem to have don't have access to created website from local, then why I have central administration website access.

Please provide the information that why I'm not able to use the other website from local system.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To be able to navigate a site you need to first create a web application and then create a root site collection. Looks like you didn't do the second.

Comment: Apologies, for not including the complete information. I have created a solution and after that a site collection for it. The website is accessible from server not from my local system. If there is any problem in local then why central administration website is getting view in the browser of local system.

Comment: To navigate from other locations you will need either create and entry in your dns or an entry in your host file. Any of this entries should match with the one you asigned in the alternate access mappings or the web application url you used when configuring it

Comment: Anybody can help me to get the idea on why SharePoint application is not running in the local system but is running fine in the server. Also SharePoint administration is running in both local and server. I'm using IP address with port number, not using any DNS name to access the website from local...Why sharepoint web application is not running in the local where as SharePoint administration running fine on the same local system...Any idea where to configure to make the SharePoint application to be accessible in the local. I have used  alternate access mapping also, but not working.

Comment: What is the address of your web application when navigating from local server? What is the address asociated to this web app?

Comment: finally fixed it..It was a firewall issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the issue..It was more with the firewall issue.

Normal firewall doesn't allow any incoming port which is less than 1023. These port numbers are used by the server internally.. I have create a inbound rule for port number 90 and allowed to all connections.

Comment: Glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a different solution which did solved the issue. All you need to go to your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and double click `Host` enter your SharePoint 2013 Server IP address and space the URL name( `192.168.0.56` `Hot.contoso.com`). This should work.